# Angular 2 custom HTTP error handling using component

Tags: angular, ionic2

This is what I have so far:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'error-handler',
  templateUrl: 'error-handler.html'
})
export class ErrorHandlerComponent extends ErrorHandler {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log("ErrorHandlerComponent, error.status: ", error.status);
    this.text = error.message;
  }
}
```

But my the flow doesn't go into handleError, I get the below error:

```
polyfills.js:3 Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ErrorHandler needs to be an `@Injectable`, not a `@Component`. It doesn't have a view associated with it - it's a service. It should look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  handleError(error) {
    // do whatever

    super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to associate a view with it, be able to put that view in multiple places:
<error-handler></error-handler>

Comment: I tried your way, it still doesn't go into the handleError

Comment: You have to provide it in your AppModule's provider list: `providers: [...,
 {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}, ...]`

Comment: This is a global error handler. If you're trying to handle the error for a specific HTTP call then handle that in the component its located in using `.catch` on the http observable.

Comment: I have that:
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerComponent } already

Comment: You don't need to extend ErrorHandler to deal with HTTP errors. You can `.catch()` HTTP errors from the observable that angular's HttpClient gives you.

Comment: I have the extend ErrorHandler

Comment: matmo, I want to catch my HTTP errors globally that's why I'm extending.